# Benchmarking generates files with possibly missing or unnecessary trait impls

Tags: benchmarking

After building my node (tag monthly-10-2021) with `--features runtime-benchmarks` and/or `--all-features`, I tried to run benchmarks for the pallets and then use them for `WeightInfo` on various pallet configuartions. [Besides pallet_election_phragmen and pallet_election_provider_multi_phase not even successfully completing their benchmarks](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/990/unable-to-run-election-provider-multiphase-benchmark), I get these errors:

```sh
     Compiling node-template-runtime v3.0.0-monthly-2021-10 (/home/node-template/runtime)
  error[E0407]: method `check_equivocation_proof` is not a member of trait `pallet_babe::WeightInfo`
    --> /home/node-template/runtime/src/weights/pallet_babe.rs:36:2
     |
  36 | /     fn check_equivocation_proof(x: u32, ) -> Weight {
  37 | |         (118_979_000 as Weight)
  38 | |             // Standard Error: 274_000
  39 | |             .saturating_add((2_965_000 as Weight).saturating_mul(x as Weight))
  40 | |     }
     | |_____^ not a member of trait `pallet_babe::WeightInfo`

  error[E0407]: method `check_equivocation_proof` is not a member of trait `pallet_grandpa::WeightInfo`
    --> /home/node-template/runtime/src/weights/pallet_grandpa.rs:36:2
     |
  36 | /     fn check_equivocation_proof(x: u32, ) -> Weight {
  37 | |         (104_612_000 as Weight)
  38 | |             // Standard Error: 37_000
  39 | |             .saturating_add((169_000 as Weight).saturating_mul(x as Weight))
  40 | |     }
     | |_____^ not a member of trait `pallet_grandpa::WeightInfo`

  error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `plan_config_change`, `report_equivocation`
    --> /home/node-template/runtime/src/weights/pallet_babe.rs:35:1
     |
  35 | impl<T: frame_system::Config> pallet_babe::WeightInfo for WeightInfo<T> {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `plan_config_change`, `report_equivocation` in implementation
     |
     = help: implement the missing item: `fn plan_config_change() -> u64 { todo!() }`
     = help: implement the missing item: `fn report_equivocation(_: u32) -> u64 { todo!() }`

  error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `report_equivocation`
    --> /home/node-template/runtime/src/weights/pallet_grandpa.rs:35:1
     |
  35 | impl<T: frame_system::Config> pallet_grandpa::WeightInfo for WeightInfo<T> {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `report_equivocation` in implementation
     |
     = help: implement the missing item: `fn report_equivocation(_: u32) -> u64 { todo!() }`

  Some errors have detailed explanations: E0046, E0407.
  For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0046`.
  error: could not compile `node-template-runtime` due to 4 previous errors
```

What could have possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pallet Grandpa and Babe currently do not have automatic benchmarks.
They have some default weight files [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/grandpa/src/default_weights.rs) and [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/babe/src/default_weights.rs) instead.

The setup for these benchmarks is very complicated and currently it needs some manual tweaking to work.
Did you modify your node? Since the [default](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/7c342164629e7871b4ee3f09de3d4e130bef6543/runtime/src/lib.rs#L328) runtime config for the node template does not list these benchmarks.
Or are you not using the template?

Comment: It's a modification of the node-template, yes.

Comment: Could you shed light on the question I linked, it is related .

Comment: I don't know why the election benchmarks are not working. Only from Babe and Grandpa I know they don't.

Comment: Okay I believe that we have to write a struct `WeightInfo` in those files and we are good to go right?

Comment: You can try again using [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/.maintain/frame-weight-template.hbs) as `--template` argument if it is just a syntax error.

Comment: I wanted to ask about this as well. It seems even polkadot and kusama runtime use the default weights. But the important question is how should the two parameters, validator_count and MAX_NOMINATORS should be customized for each runtime:   `// we take the validator set count from the membership proof to
  // calculate the weight but we set a floor of 100 validators.
  let validator_count = validator_count.max(100) as u64;

  // worst case we are considering is that the given offender
  // is backed by 200 nominators
  const MAX_NOMINATORS: u64 = 200;`